# Open cv errors after adding library

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to sort out these errors but can't:
[image]

Comment: please mention details

Comment: By adding library(opencv) into the ADT , these types of errors found 

[2015-08-30 01:22:38 - OpenCV Tutorial 1 - Camera Preview] Manifest attribute 'minSdkVersion' is set to 'integer'. Integer is expected.